# firebase nested objects returning null - javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the nested child objects like in the images but it is returning null. I want values of price and quantity and show them in table.

Check this database image
[here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1lct.png)

Code

```
var countRef = firebase.database().ref('Orders/' + listid);
countRef.on('value', snapshot => {
var b = snapshot.child("price").val();
var c = snapshot.child("quantity").val();
    console.log(c);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing to the wrong path that's why you are getting null. Here is what the Firebase docs say:

> If there is no data, the snapshot returned is null.

I can't see your entire database structure from the image but try to double check the path and here is my best guess:

```
var foodItems = firebase.database().ref(`Orders/'${listid}/foodItems`)
foodItems.on('value', snapshot => {
   // the snapshot should return the foodItems array
   snapshot.forEach((obj) => {
          console.log(obj.price)
          console.log(obj.quantity)
   })

})
```

Comment: Can you please tel me how can i clear the table? I am using material dialog and material table. When button is clicked its shows dialog containing able, but every time button is clicked it adds new data below previous one.

Comment: @Ganesh post another question with the full code so I can help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707676/how-to-clear-table-inside-a-dialog-when-dialog-is-closed check it here

Answer (score 0):

If your `listid` is and exist key, then you mistyped  the path: `fooditems` so try this;

```
var countRef = firebase.database().ref('Orders/' + listid);
countRef.on('value', snapshot => {
if (snapshot.exists()) {
   var b = snapshot.child("fooditems/price").val();
   var c = snapshot.child("fooditems/quantity").val();
    console.log(c);
}
});
```