# How to clear table inside a dialog when dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, html

When the button is clicked, 2 sets data is added. I use material design.

Button needs 2 clicks to run function for first time. Due to this, the data is added to table 2 times.

Code

HTML

```
<button onclick="purchaseList(orderid)" id="dialog">Button</button>
```

JS

```
function popup(listid) {

    var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('Orders/' +
        listid).child('foodItems');
    starCountRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {

        var snaps = snapshot.val();
        var itemPrice = snaps.price;
        var itemName = snaps.productName;
        var itemQuantity = snaps.quantity;

        console.log(itemName);
        $("#producttable").append(
            '<tr><td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">' + itemName +
            '</td><td>' + itemQuantity + '</td><td>' + itemPrice + '</td></tr>'
        );
    });

    var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
    var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#dialog');
    if (!dialog.showModal) {
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {


        dialog.showModal();

    });
    dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {

        var element = document.getElementById("producttable")
        while (element.lastChild) {
            element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
        }
        dialog.close();

    });

}
```

Comment: you can use dialog close event to clear it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Comment: @Ganesh there is no `;` in  this line `var element = document.getElementById("producttable")`

Comment: corrected that one, can you help me with double click problem?

Comment: @Ganesh details in question is not enough

Comment: that is whole function, added html also

Comment: so you want to close dialog on second click?

Comment: No, dialog need 2 clicks to open for first time. After that it opens on single click.

Comment: @Ganesh checkout my updated ansswer to your concerned problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var element = document.getElementById("producttable")
while (element.lastChild) {
    element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
}
```

Add this as necessary.

Comment: Its working, But still it adds two sets of data due to first two clicks. Any solution for it?

Comment: @Ganesh You've cropped a significant amount of code off the top. I can't tell when the first bit of code is run.

Comment: That is all in the function, Still i will add the whole function again. check it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change your firebase function from using `.on` to `.once` to avoid multiple additions of data to your table and as your data isn't expected to change frequently or require active listening you better use `.once` for performance benefits.

```
firebase.database().ref('Orders/' + 
    listid + '/foodItems').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            // the rest of your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this remocve element with class name "`.mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric`"
when user click `.close`

```
dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function () {

    dialog.close();
         $(".mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric").remove();
});
```

UPDATE:

to open dialog on 2nd click use pseudo element to activate like this

```
<div class=pseudo><button onclick="purchaseList(orderid)"id="dialog" disabled>Button</button></div>
var i=0;
$('.pseudo').click(function(){
 i++;
  if(i==2){
   $("#dialog").prop('disabled',false);
 }
});
```